# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "geo_detail" is of type point but expression is of type bytea any solution please?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Entity

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "Point") 
private Point geoDetail
```

---

Service

```
order.setGeoDetail(new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(Double value,double value)));
```

---

application.properties

```
@dialect spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

---

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "geo_detail" is of
>   type point but expression is of type bytea   Hint: You will need to
>   rewrite or cast the expression.
>
> database - geo_detail -datatype->Point

Answer (score 0):

I think that the deal is your `geo_detail` column contains `id` of `geoDetail` and you are trying to get Object while receiving Long.
Use `@JoinColumn(name = "geo_detail")`.

Comment: Hi Roman ,Thank you for time,i think you misunderstood i have created the entity field of type Point  and restricted column in postgresql as POINT when i am setting value for point as eg-:POINT (77.6879585 12.9377677) i am getting  error -column "geo_detail" is of type point but expression is of type bytea Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: Can you put here code for both of your entities (Point and entity with field "geoDetail") and your schema for this entities.

Comment: Entity
public class Orders {
 
 Id
 GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long orderId;
Column(columnDefinition = "Point") 
 private Point geoDetail;
 
 
 public Point getGeoDetail() {
  return geoDetail;
 }


 public void setGeoDetail(Point geoDetail) {
  this.geoDetail = geoDetail;
 }
 }

Comment: ========================
 
 this is how i am calculating point from double lan-lat
 
 order.setGeoDetail((Point)new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(ordersModel.getGetLat() , ordersModel.getGetLot())));//POINT (77.6879585 12.9377677)
 
 
 
 ======
 
 spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

Comment: My requirement is to store geoLocation  in form of point which i am getting from UI in form of double data type .